# How to search for each row of a column in another column

Tags: r

A table with many rows, but for simplicity of the problem...

```
> df <- data.frame(V1=c("dfafddf","B,C:Moll,A","","a bA.Capple","","adfadew"),
                   V2=c("1","2","3","4","5","6"),
                   V3=c("apple","Moll","nancy","NA","NA","NA"))


   V1               V2        V3
1  dfafddf           1         apple
2  B,C:Moll,A        2         Moll
3                    3         nancy
4  a bA.Capple       4         NA
5                    5         NA
6  adfadew           6         NA
```

So what I am trying to do is search for V3 column in V1 column and create a new column of V2 in which V3 was found in V1.

Like for example, apple of V3 is found in 4th line and Moll is found in 2nd line. So,

Desired output looks like

```
      V1               V2        V3         V4
1  dfafddf           1         apple        4
2  B,C:Moll,A        2         Moll         2
3                    3         nancy        NA
4  a bA.Capple       4         NA           NA
5                    5         NA           NA
6  adfadew           6         NA           NA
```

I have tried the below, but wouldn't give me desired result.

```
transform(df, V4=mapply(grepl, pattern=df$V3, x=df$V1)
```

**NOTE:** V3 can occur more than once in V1

Comment: This error shows up "Error in which(grepl(a, df$V1)) : argument to 'which' is not logical"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
df$V4 <- sapply(df$V3,function(x) df$V2[grep(x,df$V1)[1]])

df
           V1 V2    V3 V4
1     dfafddf  1 apple  4
2  B,C:Moll,A  2  Moll  2
3              3 nancy NA
4 a bA.Capple  4    NA NA
5              5    NA NA
6     adfadew  6    NA NA
```

If there is more than one match in V1, the code above returns the value of V2 corresponding to the first one.

To get all matches, it is probably best to save it as a separate list, otherwise you might have nested cells in the dataframe, which can get messy!...

```
allMatches <- lapply(df$V3,function(x) df$V2[grep(x,df$V1)])
```

Alternatively, you could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  These create tibbles which allow multiple values in a cell, and the `tidyr` function `unnest` will then spread these to create a separate row for each value.  So something like...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>%  mutate(V4=lapply(V3, function(x) df$V2[grep(x,df$V1)])) %>% unnest(V4)
```

For some reason this drops rows for which V3 is `NA`, but it at least gives you the results you want in a tidy format.

You can achieve a similar thing in base R with

```
lst <- lapply(df$V3,function(x) df$V2[grep(x,df$V1)])
names(lst)<-df$V3
as.data.frame(stack(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, But how to get all the matches ?

Comment: See amended answer above.  If there is more than one match, you are better off working with a list, rather than trying to squeeze a list of values in a single cell of a dataframe.

Comment: Can we use sapply to collapse the list ?

Comment: Yes, but if there are any entries with more than one match, then it will stay as a list.

Comment: I've made a couple of changes to make sure it still works if V2 does not happen to equal the row numbers.

Comment: yup thanks!, but still trying to figure out about the more than one case...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147639/discussion-between-eta123-and-andrew-gustar).

Answer (score 1):

In order to simplify the issue,

```
a<-letters[1:26]#a,b,c...z
b<-letters[1:13]#a,b,c...m

b[b %in% a]#the elements of b contained in a
```